# How to add mulitple data shopping cart functionality in codigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have used default cart codeigniter functionality,

This is code :

```
$data = array(
           'id'      => 'sku_123ABC',
           'qty'     => 1,
           'price'   => 39.95,
           'name'    => 'T-Shirt',
           'options' => array('Size' => 'L', 'Color' => 'Red')
        );

$this->cart->insert($data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
$data = array(
           array(
                   'id'      => 'sku_123ABC',
                   'qty'     => 1,
                   'price'   => 39.95,
                   'name'    => 'T-Shirt',
                   'options' => array('Size' => 'L', 'Color' => 'Red')
                ),
           array(
                   'id'      => 'sku_567ZYX',
                   'qty'     => 1,
                   'price'   => 9.95,
                   'name'    => 'Coffee Mug'
                ),
           array(
                   'id'      => 'sku_965QRS',
                   'qty'     => 1,
                   'price'   => 29.95,
                   'name'    => 'Shot Glass'
                )
        );
```

$this->cart->insert($data);